# which data type in java can support 10e+10000 number .?

Tags: java, types

i want to check for palindrome of square of 10e+100 in java.
please mention any solution of it because in java double can carry only upto 
`4.9e-324 to 1.8e+308` numeric values , so please suggest any possible solution or hint may also be helpful...

thanks for your sincere attention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to look into the `BigInteger` class. [Here](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=f&rct=j&url=http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html&q=&esrc=s&ei=ciBpUe_CHaPy0gWrsICgDA&usg=AFQjCNHZDF_dAB1Xq4M7kZFRnWRY-gXXRw) is the documentation.

`BigInteger` can support huge.. huge numbers!

Answer (score 1):

For numbers that large, when you only need the standard number of significant digits, it's conventional to represent the number using its logarithm, i.e. you store 10e+100 as 100*log(10) and work with that.